# Interpreting the Singular Value Decomposition of $\mathbf{A}$ in Terms of the Eigendecomposition of Functions of $\mathbf{A}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

The following excerpt is from chapter 2.8 of *Deep Learning*, by Goodfellow, Bengio, and Courville:

[image]

The full section (for context) is as follows:

[image]
[image]

---

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to give a full explanation of the excerpt (not the entire section). The following lists what I don't understand from the excerpt:

1. What is meant by "eigendecomposition of functions of $\textbf{A}$? I understand what eigendecomposition is, but I don't understand what is meant when referring to functions of them?
2. Related to the above, *why* can we interpret the singular value decomposition of $\mathbf{A}$ in terms of the eigendecomposition of functions of $\mathbf{A}$?
3. Why are the left-singular vectors of $\mathbf{A}$ the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T$?
4. Why are the right-singular vectors of $\mathbf{A}$ the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$?
5. Why are the nonzero singular values of $\mathbf{A}$ the square roots of the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$?
6. Why is the same true for $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ depend on $A$ and can be seen as functions of $A$.

**2.** See below.

**3. and 6.** If $A=UDV^{-1}$ with $U$ and $V$ being orthogonal matrices (their inverses equal their transposes), then
$$AA^T = UDV^{-1}(UDV^{-1})^T = UDV^{-1}(V^{-1})^TD^TU^T = UDV^{-1}VDU^T = U\text{diag}(\mathbf{\lambda}^2)U^{-1}$$
(using that $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal and $D$ is symmetric). 
This is an eigendecomposition of $AA^T$, where columns of $U$ are the eigenvectors and squares of singular values of $A$ are the eigenvalues of $AA^T$.

**4 and 5.** This is similar.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am reading through your answer carefully to ensure that I understand everything.

Comment: 1. Just to be sure, $A = UDV^{-1} = UDV^T$, since $U$ is an orthogonal matrix $\implies U^{-1} = U^T$?

Comment: 2. How did you go from $(UDV^{-1})^T$ to $V^{-1}(V^{-1})^TD^TU^T$?

Comment: 3. $D^T = D$ because $D$ is diagonal, right?

Comment: 4. $V^{-1} = V$ because $V$ is an orthogonal matrix, right?

Comment: 5. How did you get $UDV^{-1}VDU^T = U\text{diag}(\mathbf{\lambda}^2)U^{-1}$?

Comment: 1. $U$ is orthogonal thus $U^{-1}=U^T$.

Comment: 2. If $A$ and $B$ are two matrices such that $AB$ exists, then $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$. Thus $(UDV^{-1})^T=(V^{-1})^TD^TU^T$.

Comment: 3 : Yes. 4. I said that $(V^{-1})^T=V$. Indeed, since $V$ is orthogonal, $V^{-1}=V^T$ hence $(V^{-1})^T=(V^T)^T=V$. 5. $V^{-1}V$ cancels and $D^2=\text{diag}(\lambda)^2=\text{diag}(\lambda^2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. I understand now.